# serverless NextJS staticPages hashing folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, serverless

I use nextjs with serverless-nextjs-plugin.

I find revalidating in nextjs useful, but I don't think it's a good idea to check if there's something new with the server every specific time.

So, my plan is to remove the HTML document in s3 when a new post is updated and to deliver the new HTML when the user requests the HTML after the caching time has passed.

However, I found my static pages folder name in s3 is something like hash.

`myStaticPages path = bucketId/static-pages/Vycz0P21_blabla/restaurants/1.html`

I don't know what `Vycz0P21_blabla` is.

So, can anyone explain what `Vycz0P21_blabla` is? Can I customize that?